# SOQL - ignore custom field if non existent

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

I want to run a query like this -

```
select id from lead where inactive__c = false limit 1
```

If the org doesn't have the custom field `inactive__c`, it throws an error. Is there any way to ignore the field if it doesn't exist. Or I can also make the dynamic query based on field availability. How to check for field availability in that case?

Comment: use describe to get the field and then check if it exist and if not exist then remove the field and make dynamic soql.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for reference.

```
public with sharing class GenericSelectAllController 
{
    public List<Schema.DescribeFieldResult> fields {get;set;}
    public List<GenericFieldVO> fieldVals {get;set;}
    public String getAllQuery {get;set;}
    public SObject resultObject {get;set;}
    public String objectType {get;set;}
    public String searchId {get;set;}
    public List<SObject> vals {get;set;}
    public static final String ERROR_ID_MISSING = 'There was no id passed in the parameters. Id is required.';
    public static final String QUERY_SELECT = 'select ';
    public static final String QUERY_FROM = ' from ';
    public static final String QUERY_WHERE = ' where Id = \'';
    //Instantiate the controller. If there is no ID then send the error message to the page.
    public GenericSelectAllController()
    {
        init();
        String id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        if(id == null || id == '')
        {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,ERROR_ID_MISSING));
        }
        else
        {
            searchId = id;
            processSchemaInfo(id);
        }
    }

    //Process the Schema information
    //1. Retrieve the global Schema Information
    //2. Iterate over the SObject Schema Information
    //2.A Retrieve the SObject Key Prefix and match to the ID passed into page
    //2.B Describe all the Fields for the SObject
    //2.C Build a Query String from all the Fields

    private void processSchemaInfo(String id)
    {
        system.debug(id);
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = SchemaManager.getSchemaMap();
        List<Schema.SObjectType> sobjects = schemaMap.values();
        List<Sobject> theObjectResults;
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDescribe;
        List<Schema.SObjectField> tempFields;
        for(Schema.SObjectType objType : sobjects)
        {
            objDescribe = objType.getDescribe(); 
            String sobjectPrefix = objDescribe.getKeyPrefix();
            if(id != null && sobjectPrefix != null && id.startsWith(sobjectPrefix))
            {
                objectType = objDescribe.getLocalName();
                Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objDescribe.fields.getMap();
                tempFields = fieldMap.values();
                for(Schema.SObjectField sof : tempFields)
                {
                    fields.add(sof.getDescribe());
                } 
                getAllQuery = buildQueryAllString(fields,objDescribe,id);
            }
        }

        resultObject = Database.query(getAllQuery);

        for(Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr : fields)
        {
            fieldVals.add(new GenericFieldVO(dfr,resultObject));
        }

    }

    private void init()
    {
        getAllQuery = '';
        fields = new List<Schema.DescribeFieldResult>();
        fieldVals = new List<GenericFieldVO>();
    }

    //Build the Query String
    private String buildQueryAllString(List<Schema.DescribeFieldResult> queryFields,DescribeSObjectResult obj, String theId)
    {
        String query = QUERY_SELECT;
        for(Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr : queryFields)
        {
            query = query + dfr.getName() + ',';
        }
        query = query.subString(0,query.length() - 1);
        query = query + QUERY_FROM;
        query = query + obj.getName();
        query = query + QUERY_WHERE;
        query = query + theId + '\'';
        system.debug('Build Query == ' + query);
        return query;
    }
}
```

In this code you will learn to use describe and make dynamic SOQL.

[Reference](http://corycowgill.blogspot.in/2011/01/building-dynamic-soql-select-all-query.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Lead` object's [DescribeSObjectResult's fields map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_fields) to see whether the `Inactive__c` field exists on the `Lead` object, and then conditionally add a clause to your dynamic SOQL query:

```
boolean hasInactiveField = 
    Lead.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('Inactive__c')!=null;
String inactiveClause = 'where Inactive__c = false ';
String soql = 'select Id from Lead ' + 
   (hasInactiveField ? inactiveClause : '') + 'limit 1';
List<SObject> leads = Database.query(soql);
```